# Sample size affecting distribution of MLE estimator

Tags: r, maximum-likelihood, likelihood

I was working on an exercise that asked to describe the graph of the likelihood and log likelihood functions for a large sample size. Specifically it is a graph of boys = 6000 and girls = 4000. Prior to this in the text there were graphs drawn for the cases of (boys = 30 , girls 20) and (boys = 600, girls = 400). The purpose of it was to illustrate that the likelihood functions get tighter due to larger sample sizes. Here is what the graphs look like in the smaller scenarios:

[image]

So I was tasked with finding the maximum likelihood and answering what the graphs of the functions would look like in this case. Doing this in R, I was able to use the optimizer and obtained what the  MLE is:

```
oLik.f = function(pb){
  return(6000*log(pb) + 4000*log(1 - pb))
}

optimize(oLik.f, interval = c(0,1), maximum = TRUE)

$maximum
[1] 0.5999985

$objective
[1] -6730.117
```

My issue arises when I attempt to draw graphs:

```
pb = seq(from = 0, to = 1, length =  1001)   # possible values for prob a boy is born

lik_q3 = pb^6000 * (1-pb)^4000
log_lik_q3 = log(lik_q3)

q3_df = tibble("pb" = pb, "lik" = lik_q3, "log_lik" = log_lik_q3)

q3_lik_graph = q3_df %>% ggplot(mapping = aes(x = pb, y = lik)) +  geom_line() + labs(x = "pb", y = "liklihood")
q3_log_lik_graph = q3_df %>% ggplot(mapping = aes(x = pb, y = log_lik_q3)) +  geom_line() + labs(x = "pb", y = "log - liklihood")

grid.arrange(q3_lik_graph, q3_log_lik_graph)
```

What happens is I end up with a flat line at $0$ for the likelihood and no line in the log-likelihood case.

What I expected to happen based on the theory was that I would perhaps get a vertical line segment at the value that maximizes the likelihoods and nothing else. But that is not coming about. Mainly because in the data frames I end up with a column of all $0$'s for the likelihood and $-\infty$ for the log-likelihood scenario.

Is my thinking of what should be happening wrong or is it a matter of not specifying the R code correctly?

Comment: You are trying to calculate the 6000th power of a number, that's way outside the range that any floating point can handle. Calculate the log of the likelihood and not the likelihood directly

Comment: Two things: would something like this work: 1) `log_lik_q3 = log(pb^6000 * (1-pb)^4000)
`
and two: is my application of what should "theoretically" happen correct?

Comment: 1) No, this has exactly the same problem, you never want to do something like `pb^6000`, use `6000*log(pb)` instead 2) yes, if by vertical line you mean a very narrow distribution

Comment: Ok. So I have to perform the algebraic transformation before I turn it into code. Thanks for the help